# Getting all subclasses from different python modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the project I wanted to create such a structure:

```
 main_module
   ├── __init__.py
   ├── base
   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   └── base.py
   └── custom_base
       ├── __init__.py
       └── custom.py
```

where **base.py** contains base handler class

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class BaseHandler(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __call__(self, something):
        pass
```

and every time there will be a need to create new handler
add to structure

```
   └── custom_base
       ├── __init__.py
       └── custom.py
```

All handlers will be used at the same time in separate .py file outside main structure.

```py
handlers = get_handlers()

for handler in handlers:
    handler("some message")
```

And there is the problem im facing. I'd like to get all subclasses of **BaseHandler** by one function, but I can't get those subclasses if python hadn't seen them before. Is there any "clean" solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had created a utility script for this purpose. I cannot claim its a "clean" approach, but it works well. See below code.

```
import glob
import importlib
import inspect
import pathlib

from main_module.base.base import BaseHandler


def get_handlers(source_package="main_module.custom_base"):
    """
    Tries to discover the handlers in the given package recursively.
    Package name from root is expected.
    """
    search_dir = (pathlib.Path(source_package.replace(".", "/"))).absolute().as_posix()
    module_files = glob.glob(search_dir + "/**/*.py", recursive=True)
    module_files = [x for x in module_files if "__init__" not in x]
    module_files = [pathlib.Path(x).as_posix() for x in module_files]
    module_files = [source_package + "." + x.replace(search_dir + "/", "").replace(".py", "").replace("/", ".") for
                    x in module_files]

    __modules = [inspect.getmembers(importlib.import_module(x)) for x in module_files]
    handlers = []
    for member_modules in __modules:
        for _name, member in member_modules:
            if inspect.isclass(member) and issubclass(member, BaseHandler) and member != BaseHandler:
                handlers.append(member)

    return handlers


if __name__ == '__main__':
    handlers = get_handlers()
    for handler in handlers:
        print(handler)
```

This script basically scans the files in the specified package, identifies the modules and picks the sub class of `BaseHandler` and returns.
Well, this could be improvised in a desirable fashion. Some cons of this approach

- If your subclasses have some partial imports, it can be a problem
- This will work based on the working directory, so its not a choice for a library[handlers in library will not be discovered]

This aims on a more automated approach of discovery. But for a foolproof solution, you can consider using a `.env` file and configure FQNMs over there as os variables and use that to load your child classes.

If it helped you in some way, I'm happy :-)

Comment: I thought about inspect! I like that! I'll try to use it.